# Oracle SQL - On Monday Extract Data from Friday, Sat & Sun and for Rest, from previous day

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM   estar.estar_traded_cash_activity c 
WHERE  Trunc(c.process_dt) = Trunc(sysdate - 1)
```

**expected result:** 03-FEB-2020 should bring results from (31-Jan, 01-Feb, 02-Feb)
and 31-Jan-2020 should bring results from (30-Jan-2020)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` operator with `TO_CHAR` as following:

```
SELECT *
FROM ESTAR.ESTAR_TRADED_CASH_ACTIVITY C
WHERE
    ( TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'MON'
      AND TRUNC(C.PROCESS_DT) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
    OR ( TRUNC(C.PROCESS_DT) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) );
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')` to truncate the date to midnight Monday (the start of the ISO week) and you can use this to compare values in a way that is independent of the `NLS` settings for date language and territory.

You can also compare on a range as this will allow Oracle to use an index on your date column (whereas using `TRUNC(your_column)` would prevent Oracle from using an index and would require a separate function-based index instead).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   estar.estar_traded_cash_activity
WHERE  process_dt >= CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')
                     THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-3)
                     ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
                     END
AND    process_dt <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```